# Python-Post - не вижу что прилетает в ответ

Tags: python, requests

Не вижу что прилетает в ответ. по `post` запросу.

```
import requests
url = 'https://village-odnoklassniki.crazypanda.ru/post/send_request/11155'
data = ({"lang": "ru"}, {"env": "Canvas"}, {"AUTH": "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%3D"})
res = requests.post(url)
print ("res")
```

Так вроде без ошибок всё обрабатывает.
Но выводит просто `res`

Comment: ну так вы и задаете программе чтобы она просто выдала `rec` как строку а не как переменную

Comment: вы пробовали выводить значение переменной `res` вместо строки `"res"`? ;)

Comment: 1) `print ("res")` -> `print("res:", res)` 2) у вас data не используется

Comment: Спасибо. как задействовать Data?

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
url = 'https://village-odnoklassniki.crazypanda.ru/post/send_request/11155'
data = ({"lang": "ru", "env": "Canvas","AUTH": "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%3D"})
res = requests.post(url, data=data)
print (res.status_code, res.text)
```